# Login to Gmail via a form on a website?

Tags: php, authentication, gmail

This question has been asked many a times, and most of the answers deal with fetching the emails using IMAP or Gmail login for a site etc. But I don't want these.

What I want is, if a user enters his Gmail Username and Password in the login form on my website, and submits it, he should log into Gmail. Meaning his Gmail session should begin, so if he opens Gmail in a new tab, he should be logged in already and should be taken to the Inbox directly. I read that cURL might be the way to go. But I need a proper solution!

I'm a fairly experienced developer, hence I'm pretty sure Google won't allow such a thing. But it's a client's requirement, and hence I'm looking for a hack to do it.

Any advice?

Comment: Is using oAuth an option? Otherwise not possible (hopefully). There should be some CSRF protection on the forms used I suspect.

Comment: Didn't come across it! Most of the close answers were using cURL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need OpenId to make this work.  Take a look at this resource: [Federated Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID)

Comment: Actually, you need oAuth - not OpenID.

Comment: Federated Login requires users to enter their credentials to Google, in order to log into other websites. Stack Overflow supports Federated Login.

Comment: Yeah, @Xeoncross - Federated Login uses OAuth, but you are correct.

Comment: FO looks promising... giving it a try!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde, this is the only legal, scalable, and safe way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening an iframe that will submit the a Gmail login form via Javascript. The goal is to get the request from the client's browser so that the client receives the logged-in cookie, so Curl won't help you.

Comment: You'll run into XSS issues with this via javascript

Comment: That is exactly what the OP wants: a deliberate XSS use.

Comment: You cannot submit a form cross-site through an iframe using javascript.  Plus, I believe google uses same-origin policies to prevent iframing their products.